# how to assign a js function to a class and get id when clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a calculator and have a mousedown and mouseup function on every id.  Is there some way to clean that up and have a function called anytime a class element is clicked and be able to get the id that's been clicked inside the function?

here's a link to a myfiddle [calculator](https://jsfiddle.net/rss81/4ygmjcLs/)

also, I noticed that when I placed my javascript directly in the JS box it didn't work, however as a script embedded in the html it works fine.  Could someone explain why?

```
 <tr>
    <td class='noborder' colspan='1' rowspan='2'> </td>
    <td id='1' class='buttons' colspan='4' rowspan='2' onmousedown="mouseDown(this.id)" onmouseup="mouseUp(this.id)" ;>1</td>
    <td id='2' class='buttons' colspan='4' rowspan='2' onmousedown="mouseDown(this.id)" onmouseup="mouseUp(this.id)" ;>2</td>
    <td id='3' class='buttons' colspan='4' rowspan='2' onmousedown="mouseDown(this.id)" onmouseup="mouseUp(this.id)" ;>3</td>
    <td id='plus' class='buttons' colspan='4' onmousedown="mouseDown(this.id)" onmouseup="mouseUp(this.id)" ;>+</td>
    <td class='noborder' colspan='1' rowspan='2'> </td>
  </tr>


<script>
function mouseDown(id) {
document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "gray";
}

function mouseUp(id) {
document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
</script>
```

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250557/use-onmousedown-to-get-the-id-of-the-element-you-just-mousedowned-on

Answer (score 1):

I realized a way how to add mousedown and mouseup events on all the elements with a class:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("buttons");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].onmousedown = function() {
        mouseDown(this.id);
        mouseUp(this.id);
    }
}
```

I tested it on [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp).

(Also, I don't know what you mean by JS Box. Sorry.)

Comment: .. why do you call mouseDown and mouseUp in the `onmousedown` handler?

Comment: is it true that that is exactly what he wanted?

Comment: Well, his HTML shows `onmousedown="mouseDown(this.id)" onmouseup="mouseUp(this.id)"` and your code would do the equivalent of `onmousedown="mouseDown(this.id);mouseUp(this.id)"`, so I don't think so.

Comment: We just need to move the mouseUp into a separate for loop and check for mouseUp event

Comment: no, this function doesn't work.  basically, anytime a class element is clicked it fires off the function but I have no way of knowing which element was clicked

Answer (score 0):

Remove the script tag, and add this to your css style:

```
   .buttons:active {
    background-color: gray;
   }
```

For calculations use something like this:

```
<script>
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0]
table.addEventListener("click",clicked);

function clicked(el){
  if (el.hasClass("buttons")){
   //magic
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: That's really good but it only get's me so far.  I obviously still need to pass the id or value that's been clicked into a js function to process

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you have an id conflict on the page. Using IDs like "1" is not recommended for this reason; better to be more specific.

In fact, there is no need to query the element by its ID anyway. You can operate directly on the element by just passing it into the handler. E.g.

```
<td class='buttons' onmousedown="mouseDown(this)" onmouseup="mouseUp(this)" >1</td>

<script>
function mouseDown(element) {
  element.style.backgroundColor = "gray";
}

function mouseUp(element) {
  element.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
</script>
```

EDIT: As @bgaury mentioned, a CSS `active` pseudo class is a far better option for this use case however.